# How do I know if I have "foreign" packages left in my Linux

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I am on Mint 17.3 Rosa based on Ubuntu Trusty.

I recently purged all PPAs which there were like 20+ of them.

I'd like to check if there are any remnants of PPAs in general, because currently I have no PPA imported.

I know how to check a single (or set of packages) with `apt-cache policy`.

How can I achieve that for all packages installed in my system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`apt-show-versions`](https://tracker.debian.org/apt-show-versions) for this. Running it will list all installed packages, with their origin and the installed version, and various messages depending on the available versions:

- "newer than version in archive" if the installed version is newer (and should perhaps be downgraded in your scenario)
- "No available version in archive" if none of the configured repositories contains the package
- "upgradeable" if a newer version is available, and `apt-get upgrade` would install it
- "*manually* upgradeable" if a newer version is available, but requires manual intervention to install (*e.g.* it's from `experimental`)
- "uptodate" if the installed version matches the latest available candidate version in the repositories

Packages from PPAs which have since been removed from `apt`'s configuration should appear as one of the first two.